# How to guarantee air price quote after PNR creation on Sabre API?

Tags: api, soap, sabre

I'm trying to create a PNR with "Time to think/Fare lock" option offered by airlines like AF, KLM, LH and more. The idea is to create the PNR to temporarily "block" the price until the time limit is reached (48~72hs) but I don't know how.

I'm able to create the PNR, with CreatePassengerNameRecord, without problems and it returns the retained PriceQuote but the fare is not guaranteed until ticketed and the system will re-price the itinerary with the current fare before ticketing.

Request/response example
**CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ**

```
"CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ" : {
"version" : "2.2.0",
"haltOnAirPriceError" : true,
"TravelItineraryAddInfo" : {
    "AgencyInfo" : {
        "Address" : {
            "AddressLine" : "TEST",
            "CityName" : "TEST",
            "CountryCode" : "FR",
            "PostalCode" : "99999",
            "StreetNmbr" : "TEST 123"
        },
        "Ticketing" : {
            "PseudoCityCode" : "L4GJ",
            "TicketType" : "7TAW"
        }
    },
    "CustomerInfo" : {
        "ContactNumbers" : {
            "ContactNumber" : [ 
                {
                    "Phone" : "99999999",
                    "PhoneUseType" : "A"
                }
            ]
        },
        "CustLoyalty" : [],
        "Email" : [ 
            {
                "Address" : "test@gmail.com"
            }, 
            {
                "Address" : "testRes@gmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "PersonName" : [ 
            {
                "NameNumber" : "1.1",
                "PassengerType" : "ADT",
                "GivenName" : "TEST",
                "Surname" : "TEST"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"AirBook" : {
    "HaltOnStatus" : [ 
        {
            "Code" : "HL"
        }, 
        {
            "Code" : "KK"
        }, 
        {
            "Code" : "LL"
        }, 
        {
            "Code" : "NN"
        }, 
        {
            "Code" : "NO"
        }, 
        {
            "Code" : "UC"
        }, 
        {
            "Code" : "US"
        }
    ],
    "OriginDestinationInformation" : {
        "FlightSegment" : [ 
            {
                "DepartureDateTime" : "2021-02-17T13:15:00",
                "ArrivalDateTime" : "2021-02-17T13:45:00",
                "FlightNumber" : "1780",
                "NumberInParty" : "1",
                "ResBookDesigCode" : "G",
                "Status" : "NN",
                "DestinationLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "LHR"
                },
                "MarketingAirline" : {
                    "Code" : "AF",
                    "FlightNumber" : "1780"
                },
                "OriginLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "CDG"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "DepartureDateTime" : "2021-02-26T11:30:00",
                "ArrivalDateTime" : "2021-02-26T13:50:00",
                "FlightNumber" : "1581",
                "NumberInParty" : "1",
                "ResBookDesigCode" : "X",
                "Status" : "NN",
                "DestinationLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "CDG"
                },
                "MarketingAirline" : {
                    "Code" : "AF",
                    "FlightNumber" : "1581"
                },
                "OriginLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "LHR"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"AirPrice" : [ 
    {
        "PriceComparison" : {
            "AcceptablePriceDecrease" : {
                "Amount" : 125.3,
                "HaltOnNonAcceptablePrice" : true
            },
            "AcceptablePriceIncrease" : {
                "Amount" : 5,
                "HaltOnNonAcceptablePrice" : true
            },
            "AmountSpecified" : 125.3
        },
        "PriceRequestInformation" : {
            "Retain" : true,
            "OptionalQualifiers" : {
                "MiscQualifiers" : {
                    "BaggageAllowance" : []
                },
                "FOP_Qualifiers" : {
                    "BasicFOP" : {
                        "Type" : "CK"
                    }
                },
                "PricingQualifiers" : {
                    "ItineraryOptions" : {
                        "SegmentSelect" : [ 
                            {
                                "Number" : "1",
                                "RPH" : "1"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "Number" : "2",
                                "RPH" : "2"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "PassengerType" : [ 
                        {
                            "Quantity" : "1",
                            "Code" : "ADT"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SpecificFare" : [ 
                        {
                            "FareBasis" : "GS50OALG",
                            "RPH" : "1"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "FareBasis" : "XS50OALG",
                            "RPH" : "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"SpecialReqDetails" : {
    "SpecialService" : {
        "SpecialServiceInfo" : {
            "AdvancePassenger" : [],
            "SecureFlight" : [ 
                {
                    "PersonName" : {
                        "NameNumber" : "1.1",
                        "DateOfBirth" : "1991-01-13",
                        "Gender" : "M",
                        "GivenName" : "TEST",
                        "Surname" : "TEST"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Service" : [ 
                {
                    "SSR_Code" : "CTCM",
                    "PersonName" : {
                        "NameNumber" : "1.1"
                    },
                    "Text" : "0033142890939"
                }, 
                {
                    "SSR_Code" : "CTCE",
                    "PersonName" : {
                        "NameNumber" : "1.1"
                    },
                    "Text" : "TEST"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"PostProcessing" : {
    "RedisplayReservation" : {
        "waitInterval" : 1000
    },
    "EndTransaction" : {
        "Email" : {
            "eTicket" : {
                "PDF" : {
                    "Ind" : false
                },
                "Ind" : false
            },
            "Ind" : true
        },
        "Source" : {
            "ReceivedFrom" : "TEST"
        }
    }
}
```

}
}

**CreatePassengerNameRecordRS (partial)**

```
"CreatePassengerNameRecordRS" : {
"ApplicationResults" : {
    "status" : "Complete",
    "Success" : [ 
        {
            "timeStamp" : "2020-11-19T06:29:15.342-06:00"
        }
    ],
    "Warning" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "BusinessLogic",
            "timeStamp" : "2020-11-19T06:29:14.016-06:00",
            "SystemSpecificResults" : [ 
                {
                    "Message" : [ 
                        {
                            "code" : "WARN.SWS.HOST.WARNING_RESPONSE",
                            "content" : "EndTransactionLLSRQ: TTY REQ PEND"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"ItineraryRef" : {
    "ID" : "HOKJCQ"
},
"AirBook" : {
    "OriginDestinationOption" : {
        "FlightSegment" : [ 
            {
                "ArrivalDateTime" : "02-17T13:45",
                "DepartureDateTime" : "02-17T13:15",
                "eTicket" : true,
                "FlightNumber" : "1780",
                "NumberInParty" : "001",
                "ResBookDesigCode" : "G",
                "Status" : "NN",
                "DestinationLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "LHR"
                },
                "MarketingAirline" : {
                    "Code" : "AF",
                    "FlightNumber" : "1780"
                },
                "OriginLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "CDG"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "ArrivalDateTime" : "02-26T13:50",
                "DepartureDateTime" : "02-26T11:30",
                "eTicket" : true,
                "FlightNumber" : "1581",
                "NumberInParty" : "001",
                "ResBookDesigCode" : "X",
                "Status" : "NN",
                "DestinationLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "CDG"
                },
                "MarketingAirline" : {
                    "Code" : "AF",
                    "FlightNumber" : "1581"
                },
                "OriginLocation" : {
                    "LocationCode" : "LHR"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"AirPrice" : [ 
    {
        "PriceComparison" : {
            "AmountReturned" : "125.30",
            "AmountSpecified" : "125.3"
        },
        "PriceQuote" : {
            "MiscInformation" : {
                "BaggageInfo" : {
                    "SubCodeProperties" : [ 
                        {
                            "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : 1,
                            "RPH" : 1,
                            "AncillaryFeeGroupCode" : "BG",
                            "CommercialNameofBaggageItemType" : "FREE BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE",
                            "EMD_Type" : "4",
                            "ExtendedSubCodeKey" : "0DFAAAF"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : 1,
                            "RPH" : 2,
                            "AncillaryFeeGroupCode" : "BG",
                            "CommercialNameofBaggageItemType" : "UPTO50LB 23KG AND62LI 158LCM",
                            "DescriptionOne" : {
                                "Code" : "23",
                                "Text" : "UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGRAMS"
                            },
                            "DescriptionTwo" : {
                                "Code" : "6U",
                                "Text" : "UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS"
                            },
                            "EMD_Type" : "4",
                            "ExtendedSubCodeKey" : "0GOACAF",
                            "SizeWeightInfo" : {
                                "MaximumSizeInAlternate" : {
                                    "Units" : "C",
                                    "content" : "158"
                                },
                                "MaximumSize" : {
                                    "Units" : "I",
                                    "content" : "62"
                                },
                                "MaximumWeightInAlternate" : {
                                    "Units" : "K",
                                    "content" : "23"
                                },
                                "MaximumWeight" : {
                                    "Units" : "L",
                                    "content" : "50"
                                }
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : 1,
                            "RPH" : 3,
                            "AncillaryFeeGroupCode" : "BG",
                            "AncillaryService" : {
                                "SubGroupCode" : "CY",
                                "Text" : "CARRY ON HAND BAGGAGE"
                            },
                            "CommercialNameofBaggageItemType" : "CARRYON HAND BAGGAGE ALLOWANCE",
                            "EMD_Type" : "4",
                            "ExtendedSubCodeKey" : "0LNABAF"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : 1,
                            "RPH" : 4,
                            "AncillaryFeeGroupCode" : "BG",
                            "AncillaryService" : {
                                "SubGroupCode" : "CY",
                                "Text" : "CARRY ON HAND BAGGAGE"
                            },
                            "BookingMethod" : "04",
                            "CommercialNameofBaggageItemType" : "CABIN BAGGAGE 12KG 1PC 115CM",
                            "DescriptionOne" : {
                                "Code" : "12",
                                "Text" : "UP TO 26 POUNDS/12 KILOGRAMS"
                            },
                            "DescriptionTwo" : {
                                "Code" : "4U",
                                "Text" : "UP TO 45 LINEAR INCHES/115 LINEAR CENTIMETERS"
                            },
                            "EMD_Type" : "4",
                            "ExtendedSubCodeKey" : "0MRACAF",
                            "SizeWeightInfo" : {
                                "MaximumSizeInAlternate" : {
                                    "Units" : "C",
                                    "content" : "115"
                                },
                                "MaximumSize" : {
                                    "Units" : "I",
                                    "content" : "45"
                                },
                                "MaximumWeightInAlternate" : {
                                    "Units" : "K",
                                    "content" : "12"
                                },
                                "MaximumWeight" : {
                                    "Units" : "L",
                                    "content" : "26"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "HeaderInformation" : [ 
                    {
                        "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : "1",
                        "DepartureDate" : "2021-02-17",
                        "Text" : [ 
                            "VALIDATING CARRIER - AF", 
                            "CAT 15 SALES RESTRICTIONS FREE TEXT FOUND - VERIFY RULES", 
                            "BAG ALLOWANCE     -CDGLHR-NIL/AF", 
                            "1STCHECKED BAG FEE-CDGLHR-EUR45.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                            "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                            "2NDCHECKED BAG FEE-CDGLHR-EUR70.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                            "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                            "BAG ALLOWANCE     -LHRCDG-NIL/AF", 
                            "1STCHECKED BAG FEE-LHRCDG-EUR45.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                            "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                            "2NDCHECKED BAG FEE-LHRCDG-EUR70.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                            "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                            "CARRY ON ALLOWANCE", 
                            "CDGLHR LHRCDG-01P/AF", 
                            "01/UP TO 26 POUNDS/12 KILOGRAMS AND UP TO 45 LINEAR INCHES/115", 
                            "LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                            "CARRY ON CHARGES", 
                            "CDGLHR LHRCDG-AF-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER", 
                            "ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON", 
                            "FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/", 
                            "CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./"
                        ],
                        "ValidatingCarrier" : {
                            "Code" : "AF"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "SolutionInformation" : [ 
                    {
                        "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : "1",
                        "BaseFareCurrencyCode" : "EUR",
                        "CurrencyCode" : "EUR",
                        "GrandTotalEquivFareAmount" : "34.00",
                        "GrandTotalTaxes" : "91.30",
                        "RequiresRebook" : "false",
                        "TicketNumber" : "0",
                        "TotalAmount" : "125.30"
                    }
                ],
                "ValidatingCarrier" : [ 
                    {
                        "NewValidatingProcess" : true,
                        "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : "1",
                        "SettlementMethod" : "BSP",
                        "Ticket" : [ 
                            {
                                "Type" : "ETKTREQ",
                                "CarrierCode" : "AF",
                                "ValidatingCarrierType" : "Default"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "PricedItinerary" : {
                "AlternativePricing" : "false",
                "CurrencyCode" : "EUR",
                "MultiTicket" : false,
                "TotalAmount" : "125.30",
                "AirItineraryPricingInfo" : [ 
                    {
                        "SolutionSequenceNmbr" : "1",
                        "BaggageProvisions" : [ 
                            ...
                        ],
                        "FareCalculation" : {
                            "Text" : "PAR AF LON17.62AF PAR22.33NUC39.95END ROE0.85086"
                        },
                        "FareCalculationBreakdown" : [ 
                            {
                                "Branch" : {
                                    "PCC" : "N1GJ",
                                    "FirstJointCarrier" : "AF"
                                },
                                "Departure" : {
                                    "CityCode" : "PAR",
                                    "AirportCode" : "CDG",
                                    "AirlineCode" : "AF",
                                    "GenericInd" : "O",
                                    "ArrivalCityCode" : "LON",
                                    "ArrivalAirportCode" : "LHR"
                                },
                                "FareBasis" : {
                                    "Code" : "GS50OALG",
                                    "FareAmount" : "17.62",
                                    "FarePassengerType" : "ADT",
                                    "FareType" : "P",
                                    "FilingCarrier" : "AF",
                                    "GlobalInd" : "EH",
                                    "TripTypeInd" : "R",
                                    "Market" : "PARLON",
                                    "Cabin" : "Y"
                                },
                                "FreeBaggageAllowance" : "NONIL",
                                "RuleCategoryIndicator" : [ 
                                    "4", 
                                    "5", 
                                    "6", 
                                    "7", 
                                    "8", 
                                    "9", 
                                    "10", 
                                    "15", 
                                    "16"
                                ]
                            }, 
                            {
                                "Branch" : {
                                    "PCC" : "N1GJ",
                                    "FirstJointCarrier" : "AF"
                                },
                                "Departure" : {
                                    "CityCode" : "LON",
                                    "AirportCode" : "LHR",
                                    "AirlineCode" : "AF",
                                    "GenericInd" : "O",
                                    "ArrivalCityCode" : "PAR",
                                    "ArrivalAirportCode" : "CDG"
                                },
                                "FareBasis" : {
                                    "Code" : "XS50OALG",
                                    "FareAmount" : "22.33",
                                    "FarePassengerType" : "ADT",
                                    "FareType" : "P",
                                    "FilingCarrier" : "AF",
                                    "GlobalInd" : "EH",
                                    "TripTypeInd" : "R",
                                    "Market" : "PARLON",
                                    "Cabin" : "Y"
                                },
                                "FreeBaggageAllowance" : "NONIL",
                                "RuleCategoryIndicator" : [ 
                                    "4", 
                                    "5", 
                                    "6", 
                                    "7", 
                                    "8", 
                                    "9", 
                                    "10", 
                                    "15", 
                                    "16"
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "ItinTotalFare" : {
                            "NonRefundableInd" : "N",
                            "BaggageInfo" : {
                                "NonUS_DOT_Disclosure" : {
                                    "Text" : [ 
                                        "BAG ALLOWANCE     -CDGLHR-NIL/AF", 
                                        "1STCHECKED BAG FEE-CDGLHR-EUR45.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                                        "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                                        "2NDCHECKED BAG FEE-CDGLHR-EUR70.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                                        "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                                        "BAG ALLOWANCE     -LHRCDG-NIL/AF", 
                                        "1STCHECKED BAG FEE-LHRCDG-EUR45.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                                        "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                                        "2NDCHECKED BAG FEE-LHRCDG-EUR70.00/AF/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR", 
                                        "AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                                        "CARRY ON ALLOWANCE", 
                                        "CDGLHR LHRCDG-01P/AF", 
                                        "01/UP TO 26 POUNDS/12 KILOGRAMS AND UP TO 45 LINEAR INCHES/115", 
                                        "LINEAR CENTIMETERS", 
                                        "CARRY ON CHARGES", 
                                        "CDGLHR LHRCDG-AF-CARRY ON FEES UNKNOWN-CONTACT CARRIER", 
                                        "ADDITIONAL ALLOWANCES AND/OR DISCOUNTS MAY APPLY DEPENDING ON", 
                                        "FLYER-SPECIFIC FACTORS /E.G. FREQUENT FLYER STATUS/MILITARY/", 
                                        "CREDIT CARD FORM OF PAYMENT/EARLY PURCHASE OVER INTERNET,ETC./"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "BaseFare" : {
                                "Amount" : "34.00",
                                "CurrencyCode" : "EUR"
                            },
                            "Construction" : {
                                "Amount" : "39.95",
                                "CurrencyCode" : "NUC",
                                "RateOfExchange" : "0.850860"
                            },
                            "Taxes" : {
                                "TotalAmount" : "91.30",
                                "Tax" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "Amount" : "26.00",
                                        "TaxCode" : "YQI",
                                        "TaxName" : "SERVICE FEE - CARRIER-IMPOSED",
                                        "TicketingTaxCode" : "YQ"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "Amount" : "16.33",
                                        "TaxCode" : "FR",
                                        "TaxName" : "CIVIL AVIATION TAX DOMESTIC AN",
                                        "TicketingTaxCode" : "FR"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "Amount" : "13.09",
                                        "TaxCode" : "QX",
                                        "TaxName" : "PASSENGER SERVICE CHARGE INTER",
                                        "TicketingTaxCode" : "QX"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "Amount" : "1.13",
                                        "TaxCode" : "IZ",
                                        "TaxName" : "AIR PASSENGER SOLIDARITY TAX",
                                        "TicketingTaxCode" : "IZ"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "Amount" : "14.51",
                                        "TaxCode" : "GB",
                                        "TaxName" : "AIR PASSENGER DUTY APD",
                                        "TicketingTaxCode" : "GB"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "Amount" : "18.74",
                                        "TaxCode" : "UB",
                                        "TaxName" : "PASSENGER SERVICE CHARGE DEPAR",
                                        "TicketingTaxCode" : "UB"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "Amount" : "1.50",
                                        "TaxCode" : "O4",
                                        "TaxName" : "AIR PASSENGER SOLIDARITY TAX S",
                                        "TicketingTaxCode" : "O4"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "TotalFare" : {
                                "Amount" : "125.30",
                                "CurrencyCode" : "EUR"
                            }
                        },
                        "PassengerTypeQuantity" : {
                            "Code" : "ADT",
                            "Quantity" : "1"
                        },
                        "PTC_FareBreakdown" : [ 
                            {
                                "Cabin" : "Y",
                                "FareBasis" : {
                                    "Code" : "GS50OALG",
                                    "FareAmount" : "17.62",
                                    "FarePassengerType" : "ADT",
                                    "FareType" : "P",
                                    "FilingCarrier" : "AF",
                                    "GlobalInd" : "EH",
                                    "Market" : "PARLON"
                                },
                                "FreeBaggageAllowance" : "NONIL"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "Cabin" : "Y",
                                "FareBasis" : {
                                    "Code" : "XS50OALG",
                                    "FareAmount" : "22.33",
                                    "FarePassengerType" : "ADT",
                                    "FareType" : "P",
                                    "FilingCarrier" : "AF",
                                    "GlobalInd" : "EH",
                                    "Market" : "PARLON"
                                },
                                "FreeBaggageAllowance" : "NONIL"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"TravelItineraryRead" : {
    "TravelItinerary" : {
        "CustomerInfo" : {
            ...
        },
        "ItineraryInfo" : {
            "ItineraryPricing" : {
                "PriceQuote" : [ 
                    {
                        "RPH" : "1",
                        "MiscInformation" : {
                            "SignatureLine" : [ 
                                {
                                    "ExpirationDateTime" : "00:00",
                                    "Source" : "SYS",
                                    "Status" : "ACTIVE",
                                    "Text" : "N1GJ N1GJ*AWS 1329/19NOV20"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "PricedItinerary" : [ 
                            {
                                "DisplayOnly" : false,
                                "InputMessage" : "WPFCK¥S1*ZZGS50OALG¥S2*ZZXS50OALG¥P1ADT¥RQ",
                                "RPH" : "1",
                                "StatusCode" : "A",
                                "TaxExempt" : false,
                                "ValidatingCarrier" : "AF",
                                "StoredDateTime" : "2020-11-19T13:29",
                                "AirItineraryPricingInfo" : {
                                    "ItinTotalFare" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "BaseFare" : {
                                                "Amount" : "34.00",
                                                "CurrencyCode" : "EUR"
                                            },
                                            "Taxes" : {
                                                "Tax" : {
                                                    "Amount" : "91.30",
                                                    "TaxCode" : "XT"
                                                },
                                                "TaxBreakdownCode" : [ 
                                                    {
                                                        "TaxPaid" : false,
                                                        "content" : "26.00YQ"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "TaxPaid" : false,
                                                        "content" : "16.33FR"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "TaxPaid" : false,
                                                        "content" : "13.09QX"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "TaxPaid" : false,
                                                        "content" : "1.13IZ"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "TaxPaid" : false,
                                                        "content" : "14.51GB"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "TaxPaid" : false,
                                                        "content" : "18.74UB"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "TaxPaid" : false,
                                                        "content" : "1.50O4"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "TotalFare" : {
                                                "Amount" : "125.30",
                                                "CurrencyCode" : "EUR"
                                            },
                                            "Totals" : {
                                                "BaseFare" : {
                                                    "Amount" : "34.00"
                                                },
                                                "Taxes" : {
                                                    "Tax" : {
                                                        "Amount" : "91.30"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "TotalFare" : {
                                                    "Amount" : "125.30"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "PassengerTypeQuantity" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Code" : "ADT",
                                            "Quantity" : "01"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "PTC_FareBreakdown" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Endorsements" : {
                                                "Endorsement" : [ 
                                                    {
                                                        "type" : "PRICING_PARAMETER",
                                                        "Text" : "WPFCK$S1*ZZGS50OALG$S2*ZZXS50OALG$P1ADT$RQ"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "type" : "WARNING",
                                                        "Text" : "VALIDATING CARRIER - AF"
                                                    }, 
                                                    {
                                                        "type" : "WARNING",
                                                        "Text" : "CAT 15 SALES RESTRICTIONS FREE TEXT FOUND - VERIFY RULES"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "FareBasis" : [ 
                                                {
                                                    "Code" : "GS50OALG/XS50OALG"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "FareCalculation" : {
                                                "Text" : [ 
                                                    "PAR AF LON17.62AF PAR22.33NUC39.95END ROE0.85086"
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "FareSource" : "ATPC",
                                            "FlightSegment" : [ 
                                                {
                                                    "ConnectionInd" : "O",
                                                    "DepartureDateTime" : "02-17T13:15",
                                                    "FlightNumber" : "1780",
                                                    "ResBookDesigCode" : "G",
                                                    "SegmentNumber" : "1",
                                                    "Status" : "OK",
                                                    "BaggageAllowance" : {
                                                        "Number" : "NIL"
                                                    },
                                                    "FareBasis" : {
                                                        "Code" : "GS50OALG"
                                                    },
                                                    "MarketingAirline" : {
                                                        "Code" : "AF",
                                                        "FlightNumber" : "1780"
                                                    },
                                                    "OriginLocation" : {
                                                        "LocationCode" : "CDG"
                                                    },
                                                    "ValidityDates" : {
                                                        "NotValidAfter" : "2021-02-17",
                                                        "NotValidBefore" : "2021-02-17"
                                                    }
                                                }, 
                                                {
                                                    "ConnectionInd" : "O",
                                                    "DepartureDateTime" : "02-26T11:30",
                                                    "FlightNumber" : "1581",
                                                    "ResBookDesigCode" : "X",
                                                    "SegmentNumber" : "2",
                                                    "Status" : "OK",
                                                    "BaggageAllowance" : {
                                                        "Number" : "NIL"
                                                    },
                                                    "FareBasis" : {
                                                        "Code" : "XS50OALG"
                                                    },
                                                    "MarketingAirline" : {
                                                        "Code" : "AF",
                                                        "FlightNumber" : "1581"
                                                    },
                                                    "OriginLocation" : {
                                                        "LocationCode" : "LHR"
                                                    },
                                                    "ValidityDates" : {
                                                        "NotValidAfter" : "2021-02-26",
                                                        "NotValidBefore" : "2021-02-26"
                                                    }
                                                }, 
                                                {
                                                    "OriginLocation" : {
                                                        "LocationCode" : "CDG"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "FareComponent" : [ 
                                                {
                                                    "FareBasisCode" : "GS50OALG",
                                                    "FareDirectionality" : "FROM",
                                                    "Amount" : "1762",
                                                    "TicketDesignator" : "",
                                                    "GoverningCarrier" : "AF",
                                                    "FareComponentNumber" : "1",
                                                    "Location" : {
                                                        "Origin" : "PAR",
                                                        "Destination" : "LON"
                                                    },
                                                    "Dates" : {
                                                        "DepartureDateTime" : "02-17T13:15",
                                                        "ArrivalDateTime" : "02-17T13:45"
                                                    },
                                                    "FlightSegmentNumbers" : {
                                                        "FlightSegmentNumber" : [ 
                                                            "1"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }, 
                                                {
                                                    "FareBasisCode" : "XS50OALG",
                                                    "FareDirectionality" : "TO",
                                                    "Amount" : "2233",
                                                    "TicketDesignator" : "",
                                                    "GoverningCarrier" : "AF",
                                                    "FareComponentNumber" : "2",
                                                    "Location" : {
                                                        "Origin" : "LON",
                                                        "Destination" : "PAR"
                                                    },
                                                    "Dates" : {
                                                        "DepartureDateTime" : "02-26T11:30",
                                                        "ArrivalDateTime" : "02-26T13:50"
                                                    },
                                                    "FlightSegmentNumbers" : {
                                                        "FlightSegmentNumber" : [ 
                                                            "2"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "ResponseHeader" : {
                            "Text" : [ 
                                "FARE - PRICE RETAINED", 
                                "FARE USED TO CALCULATE DISCOUNT", 
                                "FARE NOT GUARANTEED UNTIL TICKETED"
                            ]
                        },
                        "PriceQuotePlus" : {
                            "DomesticIntlInd" : "I",
                            "PricingStatus" : "S",
                            "VerifyFareCalc" : false,
                            "ItineraryChanged" : false,
                            "ManualFare" : false,
                            "NegotiatedFare" : false,
                            "SystemIndicator" : "S",
                            "NUCSuppresion" : false,
                            "SubjToGovtApproval" : false,
                            "IT_BT_Fare" : "BT",
                            "DisplayOnly" : false,
                            "DiscountAmount" : "0",
                            "PassengerInfo" : {
                                "PassengerType" : "ADT",
                                "PassengerData" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "NameNumber" : "01.01",
                                        "content" : "TEST/TEST"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "TicketingInstructionsInfo" : {}
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "PriceQuoteTotals" : {
                    "BaseFare" : {
                        "Amount" : "34.00"
                    },
                    "Taxes" : {
                        "Tax" : {
                            "Amount" : "91.30"
                        }
                    },
                    "TotalFare" : {
                        "Amount" : "125.30"
                    }
                }
            },
            "Ticketing" : [ 
                {
                    "RPH" : "01",
                    "TicketTimeLimit" : "TAWL4GJ19NOV009/"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ItineraryRef" : {
            ...
        },
        "SpecialServiceInfo" : [ 
            {
                "RPH" : "001",
                "Type" : "GFX",
                "Id" : "14",
                "Service" : {
                    "SSR_Code" : "SSR",
                    "SSR_Type" : "DOCS",
                    "Airline" : {
                        "Code" : "AF"
                    },
                    "PersonName" : [ 
                        {
                            "NameNumber" : "01.01",
                            "content" : "TEST/TEST"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Text" : [ 
                        "HK1/DB/13JAN1991/M/TEST/TEST"
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "RPH" : "002",
                "Type" : "GFX",
                "Id" : "15",
                "Service" : {
                    "SSR_Code" : "SSR",
                    "SSR_Type" : "CTCM",
                    "Airline" : {
                        "Code" : "AF"
                    },
                    "PersonName" : [ 
                        {
                            "NameNumber" : "01.01",
                            "content" : "TEST/TEST"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Text" : [ 
                        "HK1/0033142890939"
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            {
                "RPH" : "003",
                "Type" : "GFX",
                "Id" : "16",
                "Service" : {
                    "SSR_Code" : "SSR",
                    "SSR_Type" : "CTCE",
                    "Airline" : {
                        "Code" : "AF"
                    },
                    "PersonName" : [ 
                        {
                            "NameNumber" : "01.01",
                            "content" : "TEST/TEST"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Text" : [ 
                        "TEST"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Do I need to specify something in CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ to freeze the fare quote ?
Is there any other action needed to access this special option offered by some airlines ?

Thank you !

Comment: For someone who knows nothing about airline reservations, how does one use the Sabre API to request a PNR?

Comment: There are a few options but you could use EnhancedAirBookRQ + PassengerDetailsRQ or CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ to create a PNR and GetReservationRQ API to retrieve it

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved if you included the relevant code :)